How to Restrict Access to Screens Based on Group Membership in PowerApps?
I'm working on access control within my PowerApps application and need to prevent users who don't belong to a specific Azure AD group (Entra ID) from accessing certain screens.
In the OnStart property of my app, I check whether the user belongs to the specified group and store this information in a boolean variable. Initially, I thought I could use this boolean value in the OnVisible property of each screen to navigate unauthorized users back to the home screen. However, I discovered that navigation actions are not allowed in the OnVisible property.
As an alternative, I've considered using a rectangle or overlay to block the screen content if the user is not authorized, but this feels more like a workaround than an optimal solution.
Are there any other ways to properly redirect users who are not authorized to view a screen and show them a notification?
Thank you very much!
Best regards.

Found a solution, I used a timer to navigate back if the user is not in the group.
